# How can i extract text from invoices based on my own data images and text extracted manually?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Without using OCR how do I read the get the text from receipt using OCR, just by training thousands of images and corresponding text.

Here is the sample image of the receipt:

[image]

Comment: Rephrased the question

Comment: how can i retrieve data from invoices by training thousands of images and corresponding text,

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to train some convolutional neural network that would be able to detect characters. By moving your character detection window over the image you should be able to extract the text.

Now, this will be incredibly brittle. Slight changes in font/colors/orientation/zoom could mess up the network. You could correct all those one by one, but you'll end up with an OCR system.

Given the amount of work required you might be better off getting an off-the-shelf OCR solution.

In any case, here's a tensorflow tutorial on convolutional networks ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)) to get you started.

Comment: for example, i have OCR text: 19Nov' 17 07:54PM --> and in my database  "date": "19 November 2017". how can i train all OCR text and the correspondence value?